# When should alstroemeria start sprouting?

Tags: alstroemeria

Three weeks ago (early March) I replanted a flower bed, with hemerocallis (daylilies) and alstroemeria (peruvian lilies); I'd bought all of those over several months last year, as I happened across them in different garden centres. The alstroemeria were in full bloom for the rest of the summer, looking very healthy. I kept them on a balcony at the front of my house (sheltered and out of the way of frost) over the winter; then when my bed was ready I planted them all out.

In the recent warm weather lots of the garden perennials (including the daylilies) have started putting up leaves and stems, but the two alstroemeria are showing nothing above ground except the dry stems from last year; I'm worried that they're dead, and need replacing - which would be best done sooner rather than later.
Should I be patient and wait for them yet?

- Location: Sheffield, northern England.
- Variety: [Summer Paradise Indian Summer](https://www.rhsplants.co.uk/plants/_/alstroemeria-indian-summer-tesronto-pbr-summer-paradise-series/classid.2000027172/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, leave them a bit longer- unless they died in the pots over winter, they might just be a bit late because they're putting out roots at the moment, although Alstroemeria are a bit later to start into growth most years anyway. I'm assuming you kept them well watered in the pots during winter, and have watered them regularly as and when necessary since they've been in the ground. If no growth appears by mid to end of April, then you may  need to replace them.

Comment: Grand, I'll do that.